# how to select data from two tables of different databases using dblinks in oracle?

Tags: oracle, select, multiple-databases, dblink, database-link

i have a table t1 in database A and another table t2 in another database B.
how can we select data from them without using qualifiers directly..
just as database1.table1.something.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query it with fully qualified names such as SCHEMA.TABLE@DBLINK.
If you don't want to use the @DBLINK notation while querying from database A you can mask the @DBLINK in a view (In database A) and query that view instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW remote_table [(column_list)]
AS select * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE@DBLINK;
```